# Can we use multiple AND conditions for the same column in WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried using `AND` for the same column in `WHERE` clause, but it is not giving me any output. But there are two Customer names in the data set which satisfies the given condition. Where have I gone wrong?

```
SELECT CONCAT(c.CustFirstName," ",c.CustLastName) AS CustomerName
FROM Musical_Preferences mp
JOIN Customers c ON c.CustomerID = mp.CustomerID 
WHERE mp.StyleID = 15 AND mp.StyleID = 24;
```

This above query worked fine when I put `OR` for same column in `WHERE` clause, but why not for `AND`?

My data:

```
CustomerID  CustFirstName   CustLastName    CustStreetAddress       CustCity    CustState   CustZipCode CustPhoneNumber CustomerID  StyleID PreferenceSeq
10001       Doris           Hartwig         4726 - 11th Ave. N.E.   Seattle     WA          98105       555-2671        10001       10      2
10001       Doris           Hartwig         4726 - 11th Ave. N.E.   Seattle     WA          98105       555-2671        10001       22      1
```

[image: More data in image]

Comment: This should work. You defined the exact same conditions `mp.StyleID = 24 and mp.StyleID = 24`. Can you show some example data?

Comment: Im voting to close as 'beyond daft'

Comment: *"looks like MySQL workbench is only considering the first condition"*: what makes you say so? What data you have in your table, what output did you expect, what do you get instead?

Comment: CustomerID CustFirstName CustLastName CustStreetAddress CustCity CustState CustZipCode CustPhoneNumber CustomerID StyleID PreferenceSeq
10001 Doris Hartwig 4726 - 11th Ave. N.E. Seattle WA 98105 555-2671 10001 10 2
10001 Doris Hartwig 4726 - 11th Ave. N.E. Seattle WA 98105 555-2671 10001 22 1

Comment: The data is in the above form for the two tables involved in the query. I am supposed to get two names but I am getting none. But when i debug i found out that there are two names for the specified condition.

Comment: @trincot Yeah I misunderstood the output. I am editing it. I am not receiving any output values but I am supposed to get two names for the specified condition.

Comment: @Sree can you put that data in the question rather than a comment? you cannot format it in a comment

Comment: @Mr.Mindor Done, added an image link with data set.

Comment: Am I blind? I don't see any evidence of records with a StyleID of 24. The only place I even see 24 at is in the middle of a couple copies of a phone number,

Comment: I commented this in reply to an answer, but I'll restate it here.
Sree seems to be wanting an answer to the question "How do I get a list of customer names who each like BOTH style 15 and style 24" (not a list of customers that like either one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition `StyleID = 15 AND StyleID = 24` can never return anything because it can never be true. So what you're getting is expected. If you want to get the customers that have both `StyleID` 15 and 24 (in different records), then you need to group the records by customer:

```
SELECT CONCAT(c.CustFirstName," ",c.CustLastName) AS CustomerName
FROM Musical_Preferences mp
JOIN Customers c ON c.CustomerID = mp.CustomerID 
WHERE mp.StyleID IN(15, 24)
GROUP BY c.CustomerID, c.CustFirstName, c.CustLastName
HAVING COUNT(mp.CustomerID) = 2;
```

I added `c.CustFirstName` and `c.CustLastName` to the `GROUP BY`. Alternatively, you can only group by the ID and then use `MIN()` or `MAX()` on the first and last name. Both ways are more or less then same.

This query will only work if your data can never have a customer with the same `StyleID` more than once (example: customer 1001 has 3 records with `StyleID` 15, 24, and 24).

Comment: to handle multiple rows with the same styleid,  `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT mp.styleid) = 2`

Answer (score 1):

WHERE conditions operate on rows created by the FROM clause, not across rows if you try `WHERE somefield = 1 AND somefield = 2` you will never get results, a field cannot have two values at the same time.

I think what you are looking for is

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE somefield IN (15, 24)
GROUP BY ...
HAVING COUNT(DISINCT somefield ) = 2
;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your query with a single condition does not return any row, your query won't return any row.

Please try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(c.CustFirstName," ",c.CustLastName) AS CustomerName
FROM Musical_Preferences mp
JOIN Customers c ON c.CustomerID = mp.CustomerID 
WHERE mp.StyleID = 24;
```

Does it return anything?

Comment: No, It gives results without WHERE condition as well. I tried it and it gave me all the CustomerNames a total of 36 rows.

Comment: What about a **single** `WHERE` condition?

Comment: When I tried with only 'where mp.StyleID = 24' it gives 2 results which is correct and Similarly when I tried with 'where mp.StyleID = 15' it gives 3 results which is again correct. For StyleID = 15 and StyleID = 24 there are two customers and I am supposed to get those two names but I am getting no results.

Comment: I kind of give up. This is such a simple case that -- if true -- deserves to be filed as a MySQL bug. What MySQL version are you using?

Comment: And how on earth do you expect `StyleID = 15 and StyleID = 24` to give you any results? You probably missed some logic classes at school. That condition means that `StyleID` must be 15 and 24 at the same time in the same record , how can that ever happen?

Comment: *I kind of give up. This is such a simple case, that if true, deserves to be filed as a bug of MySQL*. Wow, it seems you probably missed some logic classes at school too.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought he was talking about two separate cases: 15, and 24. Isn't it the case?

Comment: *I thought he was talking about two separate cases: 15, and 24*, read the condition again `StyleID = 15 and StyleID = 24`. He already told you what he gets for the two separate cases, 2 for `StyleID = 24` and 3 for `StyleID = 15`.

Comment: I think what @Sree is trying to get is "those customers who like BOTH style 15 and 24"

Comment: @ShadowRadiance Yes, exactly. And he successfully tried something like `StyleID = 15 OR StyleID = 24`, but he somehow seems to expect some result from `StyleID = 15 AND StyleID = 24`. Obviously, he's thinking of it in English, not math/logic.

Comment: @RacilHilan The OR won't work as written; it returns all the customers that like EITHER style 15 or 24 - he wants the list of customers that like BOTH

Comment: Can you maybe help with "what query would I execute to get a list of customer names that like both styles?"

Comment: Sorry. I was unclear - my meaning was "I think the OP wants a thing he didn't explicitly ask for" - he is expecting the WHERE-AND to return "folks who like Jazz and Rock", since his WHERE-OR did (happen to) return "folks who like Jazz or Rock". 
Perhaps he should open another question, rather than fixing this one...